# django onchange submit for entire form

Tags: django, forms

I know this has been addressed before but I am having trouble making an on change submit work.  Here is my forms.py nothing special in the model or the view.  I relize I only selected this for one field but if it worked I would apply it to the others?

```
#forms.py
from django import forms
from .models import rapidTill

class RapidTillForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        widgets = {'linkArms': forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'onchange': 'RapidTillForm.submit();'}), 'shank':forms.RadioSelect,
        'caddy':forms.RadioSelect, 'liftAssist': forms.RadioSelect, 'folding': forms.RadioSelect}
        fields = ['rows', 'space', 'folding', 'shank', 'caddy', 'linkArms', 'liftAssist','shank',]
        model = rapidTill
```

and my form-template.html

```
{% for field in form %}
    <span>{{field.errors}}</span>
    <label>{{field.label_tag}}</label>
    {{field}}</br>
{%endfor%}
```

Answer (score 1):

the 'submint' does not require the Model name at the front

```
class RapidTillForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        widgets = {'linkArms': forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'onchange': 'submit();'}), 'shank':forms.RadioSelect,
        'caddy':forms.RadioSelect, 'liftAssist': forms.RadioSelect, 'folding': forms.RadioSelect}
        fields = ['rows', 'space', 'folding', 'shank', 'caddy', 'linkArms', 'liftAssist','shank',]
        model = rapidTill
```